# Problems integrating svgcanvas in angular project - 'loader to handle this file type' error

Tags: angular, svg

I tried to integrate svgcanvas in a angular project to create our own SVG-Editor GUI with the gread editor from svgedit.
I installed the plugin with npm and tried to instantiate a new Canvas inside a angular component:

```
import SvgCanvas from '@svgedit/svgcanvas';
```

```
const container = document.querySelector('#editorContainer');

const config = {
  initFill: { color: 'FFFFFF', opacity: 1 },
  initStroke: { color: '000000', opacity: 1, width: 1 },
  text: { stroke_width: 0, font_size: 24, font_family: 'serif' },
  initOpacity: 1,
  imgPath: '/src/editor/images',
  dimensions: [ 500, 300 ],
  baseUnit: 'px'
}

this.canvas = new SvgCanvas(container, config);
```

But i'm not able to use it. I get the error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@svgedit/svgcanvas/dist/svgcanvas.js 8:4068
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:4068)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)

It seems that this is a Problem with Typescript that does not understand how to mange the js-File. I never had such a problem with a npm-imported dependency and cant find any solution for that. Maybe someone can help?

Regards
Michael

Comment: This must have something to do with your setup. I cannot replicate this error on StackBlitz at all - see a working version here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pgrpmh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: That was my first thought. But i started a new angular project and had the same Problem. Maybe this is a problem with Webpack but i have no experience in Webpack.

Comment: Which version of the angular cli are you using? Because on 14.2 it seems to work in a new project.

Comment: Angular 13. But yesterday i tried on another computer and there it worked. Maybe it depends on the node version. I will update node and npm and make a new test on my main System.

Comment: That might indeed be the culprit -  at least it seems to have something to do with your specific machine then. I could verify it working with the newest LTS Node version (16.17.0) on both of my machines (MacOS and Windows).

Comment: Yes, it seems, that the problem is my old version of angular cli. After a update and creating a new project it worked. Now the challenge is to update the old project (its a big project). But this seems to be the solution.

Comment: Glad you found it! Check out the ng update command to help with updating the code base - this made it quite painless for us to update ours. Also, consider adding what you found out as an answer if anyone else stumbles upon this issue :)